# How to prevent submit button from submitting after textbox loses focus

Tags: javascript, asp.net, submit, onchange

I have a textbox with an onchange event. When the function fires, a hidden element is shown. However, when the onchange is fired due to a submit button click, the element is show very briefly because the submit function fires right after. Is there any way to prevent the submit button from not firing if it was the element that caused the textbox to "lose focus"?

EDIT:

jquery 1.3.2

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function phoneChanged(currentElement, valueToCompareAgainst) {
        $('#divPhoneChanged').show('slow');
    }
</script>
<div id="divChange">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhoneCell" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
<div id="divPhoneChanged" style="display: none; padding-bottom: 15px">
    <asp:Label ID="lblPhoneChanged" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text="Your phone number on file will be updated with the value you provided above.">
    </asp:Label>
</div>
<div style="margin-top: 10px">
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
</div>
```

And in the code-behind on the page load:

```
txtPhoneCell.Attributes.Add("onchange", String.Format("phoneChanged(this, '{0}')", strPhoneCell))
```

Comment: Please paste a small, working example using the **code snippet** editor.

Comment: The code, please. Yes, there is a way (at least one, actually), but we need your code, with jquery version (!), if you use it.

Comment: Maybe try changing the `onchange` event to trigger off `onkeyup` instead?

Comment: The above code won't trigger button click unless you intentionally click on `btnSubmit` button. Am I missing something?

Comment: I do click the button. I just want that first click to not go through and only act as if I tabbed out of the textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prepared a code using standard html code. So no asp.net. It relies on setting a global value (`startSubmit`) to `false` when the `onchange` event is triggered. The form submits only if its value is true.

**Alternatives:**

- Instead of the `startSubmit` variable you can define a hidden input whos value changes to `false` when the `onchange` event is triggered.
- Instead of using the `.submit()` jquery method you can define the `onsubmit` attribute on the `form` element .

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags must come first in the head -->

        <title>Demo - Prevent submit</title>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var startSubmit = true;

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#theForm').submit(function (event) {
                    if (!startSubmit) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        startSubmit = true; // Set to "true", so that the next click submits the form.
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                });
            });

            function phoneChanged(currentElement, valueToCompareAgainst) {
                $('#divPhoneChanged').show('slow');
                startSubmit = false;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- This random number changes on each page refresh, e.g. on each form submission. -->
        Page reloaded: <strong><?php echo rand(1, 99999); ?></strong>

        <br/><br/>

        <form id="theForm" action="" method="post">

            <div id="divChange">
                <input type="text" id="txtPhoneCell" onchange="phoneChanged(this, '4');">
            </div>

            <div id="divPhoneChanged" style="display: none; padding-bottom: 15px">
                <label id="lblPhoneChanged">
                    Your phone number on file will be updated with the value you provided above.
                </label>
            </div>

            <div style="margin-top: 10px">
                <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit">
                    Submit
                </button>
            </div>

        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

---

**Edit:**

I made many tests and I couldn't find an eleganter solution than the one above. Personally, I would have chosen to do it like @rickjerrity recommended:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function phoneChanged(currentElement, valueToCompareAgainst) {
        $('#divPhoneChanged').show('slow');
    }
</script>

[...]

<input type="text" id="txtPhoneCell" onkeyup="phoneChanged(this, '4');">
```

Comment: I'm confused. If startSubmit is set to true on load and then set to false in the phoneChanged function, how can submit ever actually submit?

Comment: Theoretical `startSubmit` should be set again to `true` if other events are triggered. But this doesn't look so flexible, indeed. I tried to find a solution strict for your question, as I understood it. I thought about the situation in your comment too, but you need to give some additional details of your perspective, e.g. the workflow you have in mind.

Comment: I have another idea. I'll test it.

Comment: I get it. I was hoping for an elegant solution, maybe one included in jQuery specifically for this but I guess I'll have to go with the variables on/off method. What you're missing in there is inside the the submit() function, if(!startSubmit).... else {startSubmit = true;}

Comment: Just add that bit so it's correct and I'll mark it as answered because that's the route I'm going.

Comment: @user1422348 I'll try to find an eleganter solution, cause I like your question. You don't need any _if-else_ because there is the `return true;` statement which "allows" the submit in all situations other than `startSubmit = false`. So the page then refreshes.

Comment: Not 'else return true', 'else startSubmit = true;' this way the variable can be set to true again so submit will work on the next click

Comment: @user1422348 I reedited my answer. You meant like that assignation of `startSubmit = true;` inside `submit()`?

Comment: Oh wait, ignore my last comment if you saw it before I edited it. Yes, correct the way you edited it.

Comment: I saw it already :-)) Look in my answer in 3 minutes again to see how I would have done it.

Comment: @user1422348 I reedited my answer with the "Edit" part. Thanks and good luck ;-)

Answer (score 0):

try using `preventDefault` function in the javascript.

[Prevent Default on W3 schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp)

Comment: But I don't want to prevent it always, I just want it prevented if it causes the textbox to lose focus

Comment: then i suppose you will have to use it in `onfocusout` event.

`onfocusout="someFunction()"`